# Infopath Button

Tags: outlook

I created several forms in InfoPath that have date fields.  I'm trying to create a button that will add a date from [datefield1] to an Outlook calendar.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you are an outlook Admin, yes you can.

Go to Account setting -->Click change button-->More setting-->Advance-->Add-->Ok